# How to worker node connect SQL Server though SSH (SSH Tunnel) in SPARK

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ssh-tunnel

I have 5 node running spark in production

```
Node1: Worker
Node2: Worker
Node3: Worker
Node4: Worker
Node5: Master
```

5 Node is in LAN Network, only IP of `Master Node` is public.

**Case 1**: My SQL-Server node is only enable connection in Firewall for `Node5`. when running job with spark i got this message:

> 

org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.158.6.95, executor 2):
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 42.113.207.214, port 1433 has failed.
Error: "Connection timed out: no further information.
Verify the connection properties.
Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port.
Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

> 

**Case 2**: when my SQL-Server node disable firewall then running job with spark successfully

I think i got problem when connect to SQL-Server from all `Worker` when enable firewall.

How can i setting all `Worker` connect to SQL-Server though SSH from Node5?

**Edit**: Maybe my question is not clear, I think keyword is `How to Use SSH Tunnel` when connect from worker to Sql-Server Node through Node 5

<sub>P.S: My SQL-Server can't enable connection from Worker because different network.</sub>

Comment: Did you open the firewall for all the 5 private IP's ?

Comment: @jjayadeep: I can't open the firewall for 5 IP because my `SQL-Server` is different network with 5 spark node. MySQL communicate with `Master Node` through only one Public IP

Comment: Without opening the firewall between the 2 networks you cannot connect to SQL Server. The worker nodes directly establish connectivity with the database so it is mandatory requirement.

Comment: i haven't publish ip for 4 worker, i can't add them to firewall in sql-server node